# Calling modules installed in python's site-packages from dos

Tags: python, dos

How does one call a python module that has been installed, into the folder site-packages, from the DOS/CMD prompt

I'm hoping for a nice solution like

```
python module.py arg1 arg2
```

at present I have

```
python D:\Folder\Folder\module.py Arg1 Arg2
```

which is fine for now but I will be installing these modules on other machines where I know the python path but not necessarily the package path. I wanted to know the neatest way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation on the Python command line utility:

```
-m <module-name>
     Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the __main__ module.
```

rest is here: http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Comment: Thanks a ton sorry about the RTFM Error